# How to make a dynamic curve with ZedGraph in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, zedgraph, curve

I need to create a dynamic graph in [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) where each of the points on a new curve are functions of points on the previous curve. Giving the overall effect the whole curve is moving/evolving on the axis.

I have a loop in which I calculate the next curve based on the current using my function and I store these in a two dimensional array. So, for each timestep I have all the Y-Axis values in order in my array.

I'm not sure how to go about with the actual plotting, do I need to declare a new `pairpointlist` for each curve/timestep?

I'm new to [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) and I haven't been able to find any similar problems to this on the internet. I'm a little stuck.

Any help is appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zedgraph has got an inbuilt option for Dynamic or Real time data plotting, [RollingPointPairList](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index3061.html?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data)

You just have to change the list data within the timer tick event, and you could also control the speed of rolling data.